# console.table() is automatically removing extra space which we add in values

Tags: javascript, console

This is an example code script that we try to display in the browser console.

- If we look at the script, 2 spaces were given before the pipe (|) symbol, but when we console those values using console.table() we see that those extra spaces are automatically removed.
- But the same values with spaces are displayed when console.log() is used.

Code :

```js
var exampleArray = [
  "First item in the array   | CONNECTS-AGENDA",
  "I'm the second item in this array   | CONNECTS-AGENDA",
  "Obviously i'm the last item   | CONNECTS-AGENDA"
];
console.table(exampleArray);
```

[image]

Comment: `console.table` can print its data however it wants--if you want full control of logger output across runtimes you'd need to use a generic table library.

Comment: I suspect it's using the same code the browser uses for HTML tables, so it's also using the browser's whitespace-collapsing. The console isn't meant as a general purpose output method, it's just for debugging.

Comment: @DaveNewton, How to manage full control of logger output throughout runtime. Please help us with an example. I need to display the values if there is extra space in the values

Comment: By not defaulting to the runtime's `console.table` behavior. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here--if you're trying to wedge a pseudo-table into a single table cell why not split that data and make it part of the "real" data"? Otherwise you're back to the original suggestion: use a table library and don't use `console.table`. Although the benefits of console.table in a client-side app seem minimal at best.